# Assign Static IP or narrow IP Range to GCP Cloud Function accessing data from Azure SQL Database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, azure-sql-database, ip, google-vpc

For a use case that I am working on, I am in need of ingesting data into a BigQuery dataset from an Azure SQL Database. My idea is to write a Python Cloud Function using SQLAlchemy or similar library to access the data from from the SQL Database, and in the function also ingest/load this data into a BigQuery table.

For security concerns, I would like to either assign this Cloud Function accessing the SQL database a static IP if possible, and if not an IP range so that these IP:s can be allowed to access the SQL database.

Implementing this is out of my current networking abilities, and I would highly appreciate some guidance on how this could be done. I believe creating a VPC could be one possible solution, but would appreciate more hands-on advice on how to set this up.

Kind regards,
Bertan

Answer (score 0):

You might need to ensure that the egress traffic from the cloud function is routed through a connector in a VPC network, and then using a router and a NAT with some static external IP address goes to the outer world. That IP address is to be "allowed" by a third party API your cloud function is to use.

Some details of [a cloud function egress traffic settings are provided in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#egress_settings).

In nutshell (very simplified case), from the best of my understanding, you are to create/prepare:

1. VPC Network
2. Subnet
3. Router
4. Static IP address
5. Router NAT
6. VPC Connector

And then use the VPC connector details in cloud function deployment

```
  gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME 
  --vpc-connector CONNECTOR_NAME
  --egress-settings EGRESS_SETTINGS
```

Some details - [Routing function egress through your VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#route-egress-to-vpc), and [Associating function egress with a static IP address](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip)